# Collectors(.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());) running successfully from eclipse and running from command prompt in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, automation

[image: This error not appeared in Eclipse IDE]

Problem is when i execute from my .bat file

Note: All environments are same in eclipse and default

[image]

Comment: Collectors(.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());) running successfully from eclipse and not running from command prompt in java?

Comment: Why do you post the title of your question as a comment?

Comment: Try to search for the error message:
"bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with source 1.7"

Comment: what is `allFunctional_Types`? Eclipse != `javac` compiler.

Comment: Have you considered `Collectors.<String>toList()`?

Comment: Thanks it worked for me! OldCurmudgeon.
But i want know why it worked from eclipse and why it got failed through batch file..